# Non professional website using .pro top level domain

Tags: domains

I am planning to offer a web service based on a .pro top level domain. The reason why I want to use this domain is because putting together my own domain with .pro makes a very good name.
However, I have seen that the [.pro domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.pro) is destined for certificated professionals. My website has totally a different purpose of course.

My question is about if it is adequate to use .pro domain for a different purpose than its original. Could I be penalised on search results or even have legal problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.pro's eligibility criteria was removed, so anyone can register for a .pro.

http://registry.pro/newsroom/news/pro-now-open-all